# route sub page slug to parent page template wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Currently the .htaccess file reads:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What I am trying to do is route all sub page traffic of

```
/record-detail/what-ever-record
```

to:

```
/record-detail/?record_id=what-ever-record
```

This is taking into consideration there is already a rule for all urls routing to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the rule before the other wordpress rules like so.

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^record-detail/([^/]+)/?$ record-detail/?record_id=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/record-detail [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: This just returns 404 of: The requested URL /record-detail/ was not found on this server.  I basically need to allow /record-detail to be routed to wordpress per usual as it's using it's own page template.

Comment: I updated the answer. However I thought you wanted `/record-detail/what-ever-record` to be routed to a query string .e.g `record-detail/?record_id=something`?

Comment: now it just falls back to the default 404 of the wordpress install.  To answer your question, yes I think it was routing it, but what was happening maybe was that since record-detail/ was not found, it simply stated that it was not found rather than include the full url including params?  Here's another qeuestion, is there a way to pass directly to the index.php file something like page=record-detail&record_id=$1 ?

Comment: you mean something like `http://example.com/index.php?page=record-detail&record_id=$1`? Or provide an example of what you mean.

Comment: Yea exactly since the htaccess rules don't seem to work as expected with the existing wordpress rules.  I figured we'd find some way to simply route the record-detail request directly to the index.php the way all other requests are. (i.e. add back the RewriteCond for excluding record-detail and instead add a rewriteCon specifically for record-detail and to have it routed to index.php directly.  if that makes any sense)

Comment: Then just try the edited rule above. I added the `QSA` flag to the WP rules. That way any query string you add to the URL will automatically be sent along with the request. See how that works out.